# Flush one shared KafkaTemplate<String, Object> vs flushing multiple specific KafkaTemplates<String, T>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, flush

I use `flush` method in `KafkaTemplate` to ensure the messages are successfully sent to the broker. I have different topics and different type of messages. The example of the service is below. There will be several beans of the service depending on the type of the message `<T>`. I plan to use common `KafkaTemplate<String, Object>` shared in those services.

I am worried about flushing of the same shared `KafkaTemplate<String, Object>` in different services. If I call `flush` in one service bean, apparentely it will trigger flushing all messages of all types. In general it is ok and will break nothing for me. But from performance point of view: maybe it is better to use different `kafkaTemplate<String, T>` in differnt  beans and flush different `KafkaTemplate<String, T>`?

```
public class SenderServiceImpl<T> implements SenderService<T> {
    
    // use one shared kafkaTemplate for any T beans
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    // ??? or maybe use multiple specific kafkaTemplate for specific T bean ???
    // Might it get a performance gain ?
    // private final KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<T> sendMessages(String topicName, List<T> list) {
        List<T> successList = new ArrayList<>();
        list.forEach(value ->
                kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, value)
                        .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, E> result) {
                                successList.add(value.getId());
                                log.debug("Successfully send message ...");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {
                                log.warn("Fail to send message ...");
                            }
                        }));
        kafkaTemplate.flush();
        return successList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to flush the template (unless you have a large `linger.ms` and want to pre-empt it).

Yes, it will flush everything.

Instead, you can wait on the `Future` returned by the send, to get the `SendResult`, rather than adding a listener to it to get an async callback.